# How prove there exist $\xi$ such $3af'(a)=3f(a)+a^3f'''(\xi)$

Tags: analysis

> let $f(x)$ have three  derivatives  on $[0,a]$,and such $f(0)=f''(0)=0$,
>
> show that: there exsit $\xi\in[0,a]$ such
> $$3af'(a)=3f(a)+a^3f'''(\xi)$$

I think we can use Tarlor to solve it,
$$f(0)=f(a)+f'(a)(-a)+f''(a)/2\cdot a^2+\dfrac{f'''(\eta)}{6}(-a)^3$$
$$f''(0)=f''(a)+f'''(\eta_{2})(-a)$$
But this maybe not usefull,and I have try some old methods also can't prove this problem,can you help me，Thank you

Comment: hello,this different problem,I Have try it the same methods,can,t slove it

Comment: Can you show that $\eta_{2}=\eta?$ I don't know if it is possible. In the case that it's true, your equality is very simple.

Comment: Sorry, disregard my answer below.